# How do I convert a matrix into an unweighted graph or tree?

Tags: c++, matrix, graph, tree

I have a matrix called array[][] with equal width and height dimensions. The data it contains looks like this

```
        #1    #2     #3       #4     #5    #6        #7   #8
    #1   0    100    -1       10     -1    -1        -1   100
    #2  100     0    -1       -1     10    10        -1    -1
    #3  -1     -1     0     1000    100    -1      1000    -1 
    #4  50     -1   720       -1    -1     -1       -1     -1  
    #5  -1     10   100       -1      0    -1       100    -1
    #6  -1     10    -1       -1     -1     0        50  2000
    #7  -1     -1  1000       -1    100    10         0    -1
    #8  100    -1    -1       -1     -1  1000        -1     0
```

A -1 means that there is no path from #x to #y, positive numbers mean there is. I'm trying to convert this to a graph or tree to make it easier to implement a minimum hop algorithm. Is there a simple way to convert it?

Comment: It is currently a valid graph. If you don't like weight, convert them. If you want a specific data structure, you should mention it in your question.

Comment: The way you wrote your matrix is called adjazenzmatrix, you can convert it to an adjazenzlist, nodelist or edgelist... or convert it to objects (each vertex is an object with list of edges to other verticies)... to convert it to objects is in my opinion the worse... because jumping to other not connected nodes is hard to manage... the minimum hop algorithm (bfs) is easily implementable with adjazenzmatrix or adjazentlist. So I wouldn't change the dataset...

Comment: It's already a graph. For more info, https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/breadth-first-search-or-bfs-for-a-graph/

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple. All the numbers in the matrix represent edges. The width/height is the number of verticies. 
Suppose your graph is a vector or list of verticies and edges. Then the following algorithm will do (pseudo code):

```
int dimension;
int weights[dimension][dimension]; // input
vector<int> verticies;
vector<Edge> edges; // Edge is a struct with int from, to and weight
for( i = 0 ... dimension) {
    verticies.push_back(i+1);
}

for( row = 0 ... dimension) {
    for( col = 0 ... dimension) {
        weight = weights[row][col];
        if( weight > 0) {
            edges.push_back(Edge(col, row, weight));
        }
    }
}
```